# Active storage saving attachment even after error

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Any suggestion on this front?

**partner.rb**

```
LOGO_VALIDATIONS = {
  max_size: 2.megabytes
}

has_one_attached :logo
validate :validate_logo_attachment

def validate_logo_attachment
  if logo.attached? && logo.blob.byte_size > LOGO_VALIDATIONS[:max_size]
    errors.add(:logo, 'must be less than 2 Mb')
  end
end
```

**partners_controller.rb**

```
def change_logo
  @current_partner.logo.purge
  @current_partner.logo.attach(change_logo_params[:logo])
  render_error(@current_partner.errors.full_messages) && return unless @current_partner.valid?
  @current_partner.save!
  render_success({logo_url: @current_partner.logo_url})
end
```

When I try to change the logo image which is more than 2 Mb I get the following expected error.

```
{
    "result": "failed",
    "messages": [
        "Logo must be less than 2 Mb"
    ]
}
```

But when I check the image by `rails_blob_path(@current_partner.logo, disposition: "attachment", only_path: true)`, I get the new logo image.